# Will windows.forms.sendkeys() send formatted text to ms doc/ms outlook?

Tags: c#, .net, formatting, clipboard, sendkeys

I would like to know whether it's possible to display formatted (like bold, font size) text using sendkeys.sendwait() method.

Note: The indented text string is already formatted. I need to way to print them on the application.

Is there anything I can do with clipboard?

Comment: display where? sendkeys does just that: send keys. It's not called SendKeysAndDisplayFormatted()

Comment: You would have to also send the keys that trigger the desired formatting.

Comment: @Robert, The intended text string is already formatted (font size, style and color). Will sendkeys print the formatted string or normal one?

Comment: @Mitch - Instead of specific application, I would need to send whichever application has focus on keyboard. But I expected to print formatted text only where it's applicable (example ms doc, ms office, etc)

Answer (score 2):

As Robert Harvey stated, you would have to send the keys that trigger the formatting. If you are working with a word processor that allows bold, italics, underline, you could achieve the following like this:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^BThis is bold Text!^B^IThis is italics!^I^UThis is underlined!");
```

... assuming that CTRL+B is bold, CTRL+I is italics, and CTRL+U is underline.

Comment: I suppose this would work, but it falls squarely into the "ugly hack" category. Surely there is a better way of doing what you want to automate the behavior of another program than `SendKeys`.

Comment: @Cody, Can you please let me know if there is any other way to do this?

Comment: @user: You still haven't told us what you're trying to do!

Comment: @Cody, It's kind  of auto completion feature where I need to replace a user entered text into pre-stored text string with formatting.

Comment: @user: And you know for sure that the application you're pasting the string into supports Ctrl+B for bold, Ctrl+I for italic, and Ctrl+U for underlined? Even on the Windows platform, those keyboard shortcuts aren't used by every text editor out there. And even in a program like Word, they can be customized by the user.